# alertmanager 0.25 send resolved messages as thread of original alert message

Tags: slack-api, prometheus-alertmanager

I am using alertmanager 0.25 with slack webhooks trying to thread my resolve messages as a thread of the original alert sent to a slack channel.

According to documentation and to chatgpt, this below template should work, but instead my alertmanager container fails to come up (restarting constantly) with the following error:

```
{"caller":"coordinator.go:118","component":"configuration","err":"yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 119: field thread_ts not found in type config.plain\n  line 131: field thread_ts not found in type config.plain\n  line 160: field thread_ts not found in type config.plain\n  line 171: field thread_ts not found in type config.plain\n  line 182: field thread_ts not found in type config.plain\n  line 194: field thread_ts not found in type config.plain\n  line 245: field thread_ts not found in type config.plain","file":"/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml","level":"error","msg":"Loading configuration file failed","ts":"2023-02-12T10:06:21.586Z"}
```

my alertmanager configuration looks like so:

```
- name: "default-alerts-test"
    slack_configs:
      - api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        send_resolved: true
        thread_ts: "{{ .Annotations.thread_ts }}"
        http_config: {}
        icon_emoji: ':this-is-fine-fire:'
        channel: '#monitoring-alerts'
        title: "{{ range .Alerts }}{{ .Annotations.summary }}\n{{ end }}"
        text: "{{ .Annotations.summary }}\n{{ .Annotations.description }}\nGroup Key: {{ .Labels.group_key }}"
        callback_id: '{{ template "slack.default.callbackid" . }}'
```

without `thread_ts` my configuration works fine and I am getting resolve messages to the same channel I am alerting to so its not an authetication or authorization issue.

As I understand the `thread_ts` parameter was implemented in version 0.22, so what am I missing here?

Comment: Related feature request: https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/3221 (with the same mention of the hallucinated `thread_ts`)

Comment: I actually commented on that thread as well.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done.

To represent the message about alert that is solved as a reply alertmanager would need to store `thread_ts` internally, to later use to identify which message should be replied. It currently doesn't provide such functionality.

---

Personally, I doubt that it will ever provide such: multiple problems will arise.

- Restart of alertmanager will lead to lost of these ids,
- unclear how to proceed in cases of multiple (grouped) alerts/resolves,
- unclear what to do if group of alerts is inconsistent: some are firing alerts, and some are messages of resolvement.

If future proves me wrong, progress and related discussions can be monitored in [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/3221).

---

> `thread_ts` parameter was implemented in version 0.22
> This is wrong, and I suspect is a hallucination of one of the LLMs. Please, recheck **everything** you get from them, and abstain from spreading misinformation.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link[alertManager_slackReciver](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#slack_config)

There is no way to do it,
Count less on ChatGPT

Comment: To be fair, mentioned link doesn't actually says that it's not possible. It only proves that `thread_ts` is a hallucination of one hungry for attention language model. Please consider editing this into a proper answer (maybe with a tad less hostility =) )

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35428601)